# Right way to do the changes in schema file for Soap WebServices

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am working on already written soap webservice.Now i have to introduce one more parameter in request and provide more details in response.I am using Rsa 8.
My WSDL contains two wrappers Request and Response and included a xsd file in which input and output parameters are defined.What i want to know is that do i need to do manual changes in WSDL and then in corresponding Request and Response java files or there is an auto generated way available.

I want to know the best way to do these type of changes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do the manual changes in the wsdl for adding request/response parameters and you can use wsimport to generate the codes from the updated wsdl.